# Adsense ads not showing in chrome only

Tags: adsense, adsense-anchor-ads

I'm using iframe from  another domain to show adsense ads on my main domain.
Adsense ad not showing in chrome , but working fine on another browsers. problem only in chrome. I changed domain, there ads working. so maybe chrome have some issue with my main domain.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think Adsense does not allow placing ads in iFrames, That is why the ads are not appearing due to violation.

This is from [Google](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3394713?hl=en#zippy=%2Cis-it-violating-program-policy-if-i-place-ads-on-iframe-pages-in-my-site-or-app)

> Yes, it does violate our policies. Firstly, you’re not allowed to
> place ads in a frame within another page. Secondly, you’re not allowed
> to put ads in your software, e.g., if you control both a page with ads
> and an app that loads that page, we will take action against it

Answer (score 0):

In my case adsense stoped working in latest chrome release after update,my first step was to chek it in firefox and it was worked there,second step was to test it on old chrome release and its also worked. Some issue in my case with latest chrome release and adsense exists.
Here i m talking about **Version 117.0.5938.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)** of google chrome.
So,i cant do anything, only to wait new release of **google chrome**.